# Is there a (preferably PHP) CMS that can be plugged into an existing site using bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system

I'm creating website with Twitter Bootstrap and I need to hook it up to a CMS because it is now a requirement that someone other than myself be able to edit the content (not necessarily the layout or anything).

Is there a (preferably PHP-based) CMS that I can simply "plug in" to the existing site?

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. It is not a recommendation or suggestion engine. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Please make your questions as succinct as possible. Irrelevant details like what you learned in college or the availability of screenshots aren't helpful.

Comment: You're going to need to plug Bootstrap into a CMS, not the other way around. Drupal, WordPress, etc. all have Bootstrap themes.

Comment: @meagar I'm not new to the SE network and while I understand what you are saying, details such as that are useful because it helps the answerer to know what skill level the asker is coming from.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, lol, I should have worded it differently.

Comment: @JohnConde I disagree with the premise you're bringing up. I'm asking a pretty straight forward question that can have an objective answer. Or maybe Ask Ubuntu has spoiled me?

Comment: @RolandiXor JohnConde is correct. Questions soliciting lists of software solutions are discouraged here. And your experience is irrelevant. The purpose of your question is to provide a reference for *anybody* with a similar problem, not to provide a solution specific to *you*. You could have asked "What is a good PHP CMS for somebody with little PHP experience" but that would still be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at Concrete 5, it doesn't take more than 5-10minutes to transform some static html pages into dynamic pages managed by the CMS.

http://www.concrete5.org/